# npm install no longer works but did an hour ago

Tags: node.js, npm-install

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here, this loaded fine an hour ago, but now it won't, I've removed the node modules and run npm cache clear --force, but still nothing. This is the error I'm getting. I'm certain it is something really really simple, I am completely new to javascript, so it's likely to be more obvious than you think.

```
Building: /usr/bin/node /home/rob/Development/vue-getting-started/03-data-and-events/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/home/rob/Development/vue-getting-started/03-data-and-events/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.15.5 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/home/rob/anaconda3/bin/python3" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded /home/rob/anaconda3/bin/python3 /home/rob/anaconda3/bin/python3
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /home/rob/anaconda3/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-65-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/rob/Development/vue-getting-started/03-data-and-events/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/rob/Development/vue-getting-started/03-data-and-events/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rob/.npm/_logs/2021-02-15T22_46_40_202Z-debug.log
```

Is there anyone that is familiar with this please, people are suggesting that I install python2.7 and other libraries that are in the error message. I can't read javascript, I'm learning it, but I know this is neither an issue with python2.7 or "node-gyp" as neither of these were installed when I had node running fine. This really is a newbie issue, there must be a simple fix for this.

Comment: You need to use Python2 either by updating your `PATH` in `~/.zshrc` or use a virtual environment.

Comment: Given that the latest version of node-gyp is 7.x rather than the four years old 3.8.0 that your log shows: that wouldn't be why. Python 2 was officially killed off by the Python foundation in January 2020, and node-gyp switched to python 3 in the 6.0 release, so you do need to make sure your dependencies are up to date. Update whatever package is trying to use node-gyp to compile itself to whatever its modern-node-supported-version is.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but why would you be saying that? It's 2020, python2 has been depricated, and besides, this is node.js, my question is about javascript.

Comment: Hmm, this is why I'm confused, Linux mint 20 installed last week (without python2.7 I might add) I'm brand new to javascript, I'm doing a course from 2020, I've installed node.js directly from the node site. Everything is freshly installed this week. Everything was running fine until one hour ago, why would packages have downgraded on their own, and why would something now need python2 when it didn't an hour ago. This must just be a simple issue like node-modules outside the folder, that gives a very similar error, but I can't find any this time.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have node-gyp --version7.1.2 installed.

Comment: that doesn't matter if whatever package/library you're using has a gyp file that says to use 3.8 - find out which dependency this is, and update _that_ because it needs it.

Comment: The only reason I have gyp now was to upgrade it if it was the issue, I never had it on my computer before this post. Why didn't it need it, then when the exact same source code is just recloned, now it needs an whole new bit of software, it doesn't make sense.